# 2009 Honda Accord 4-cyl

Tags: honda, accord, misfire

I changed the crankshaft. Now my car wont work when I give it the gas, it wants to shut off. Check engine light is on. Had Honda and another mechanic look at it montell me starter I think not I changed the starter. The machine said misfire x3 and downstream O2 sensor. I'm not rich and I cant let these machines keep guessing. Could this be O2 sensor. Please help

Comment: Are you sure that the valve timing is set correctly? There is no such thing as an Accord v4, only an inline 4, or a v6. If you have the v6 engine, I'd guess that one of the cam shafts is out of time, causing 3/6 cylinders to misfire. This can also cause the o2 sensor to read bad values, because the valves could be releasing unburned fuel etc. into the exhaust. I'd recommend pulling the timing belt cover and ensuring that the timing marks line up. The Honda Accord has an interference engine, meaning that a badly mis-timed engine can bend the valves, so be careful.

Comment: Another oddities with these engines is that they have a tendency to overrepresent a misfire. In my personal experience I've worked with many single cylinder misfires that reported as 3 or more cylinders misfiring.

Comment: Accord 4cylinder is what I meant

Comment: Thanks everyone  I still never found anyone to fix my car yet . But as soon as I do I'll post what the issue was. Thank you again